# как написать программу, которая печатает слово в порядке нарстания от последнего символа, Python

Tags: python-3.x

должно получиться:

```
t
st
est
test
```

а получается:

```
test
tes
te
t
```

мой код:

```
word = input("Word: ")
while True:
    if len(word) == 0:
        break
    print(word)
    word= word[:-1]
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я только начинаю изучать питон.

Comment: ну смотри - получается то же самое, только наоброт. Значит, нужно где-то изменить самую малость, чтобы стало как нужно. Ведь сможешь же сама сообразить!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот Вам решение в одну строку:

```
word = input("Word: ")
for i in range(1, len(word)+1): print(word[-i::])
```

***Это даже легче, чем сказал @Zhihar***

Answer (score 1):

вместо того, чтобы резать строку просто идите по позиции от конца к началу строки через `for` и делайте срез от позиции до конца строки

ну или от начала к концу строки, это даже удобнее, только резать придется от
`len(word) - pos - 1`

в итоге будет то, что нужно и код будет в 2 строчки

Answer (score 1):

```
word = input("Word: ")
c = 1# задаем счетчик
while c <= len(word):# использовать True - риск зацикливания
    print(word[-c::])#берем срез с отрицательным индексом, то есть с конца
    c += 1
```